# como ler um web service em soap usando parâmetros?

Tags: web-service

preciso de enviar parameteros para um web service feito em soap.

onde tenho de mandar um login, pass e dominio do web service, apos isto tenho de usar um header onde envio o token para usar o webservice.

apos isto tenho de fazer os pedidos que quero ao webservice mandados parameteros no metodos , o web service devolve por norma 
um array de dados

Comment: Que linguagem você pretende utilizar? O que já tentou?

Comment: estou a fazer em java... mas esta dificill